# How to stop dynos when 750 free hrs is over?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paas

I have a Rails app on Heroku and sometimes I use `heroku run` command that spawns one-off dyno and other times I want to run **two** `1x dyno` so my app can run only 375 hrs for free. I don't want to spend money for my test app. I would rather prefer it to stop. Is there a way to achieve it? My credit card is linked to Heroku because I use some free addons that require its presence (such as `sendgrid`).

Comment: The cost for another dyno is $35 a month. Are you sure you can't afford this? I mean.... Heroku does provide a pretty good service for free -- maybe you'd benefit from the investment :)

Comment: I agree with you and use Heroku myself, but that doesn't answer the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't turn them off automatically, but you can scale your dynos to 0 (zero) when you near the end of your 750 hours.

```
heroku ps:scale web=0 # Given you dynos are 'web' dynos
```

Comment: The problem is - I would prefer to turn them off automatically instead of looking every day how many hours are left...

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice but Heroku do not support that.